# Got no response when call GCP API status

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to purge the user events data in GCP Recommendation AI. I use the following codes:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
--data '{ "filter":"eventTime > \"2020-12-23T18:25:43.511Z\"", "force":"true" }' \
"https://retail.googleapis.com/v2/projects/[project-ID]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/userEvents:purge"
```

I successfully got the operation ID as [the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/manage-user-events) mentioned. While, when I request the operation status, it response only name without other information. And user events data in Recommendation AI are not deleted, either.

**Code:**

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
"https://retail.googleapis.com/v2/projects/[project-ID]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/operations/[operation ID]"
```

**Result:**

```
{"name": "projects/[project-ID]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/operations/[Operation ID]"}
```

I haven't try any method yet because having no idea why it happen. Thank for your opinion and answer.

Comment: Have you tried on differet project ? Have you tried anything else ? It's a simple procedure and it should work as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to engineer from GCP, he says there are something wrong about purge pipeline and they just solve it. So the events are deleted successfully. Thanks for your opinion.